# How to use permission account id for accessing video in AWS S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have uploaded a video in my `AWS S3` and I want to play the video in HTML5 video player. I don't want to make the video accessed publicly. I have been given an account user id in the permission section, but IDK how to use it. Can someone tell me how I can use my video file with my account id? Thanks.

`Video Link: https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/[THE-BUCKET]/[FOLDER]/video.mp4`.

`MY AWS ACCOUNT USER ID (for example use): 2aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa5`

`So far I have got this: https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/[THE-BUCKET]/[FOLDER]/video.mp4&AWSAccessKeyId=2aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa5`

The Problem I'm getting:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To allow a video file to be played from Amazon S3, it will need to be accessible by your users.

You can limit access by keeping the video private and then having your application generate a **Pre-Signed URL**, which is a time-limited URL that grants access to an object.

Alternatively, you can serve the video via **Amazon CloudFront**, which can serve the video via protocols that allow it to be played in a browser, but not directly downloaded.

See: [Working with RTMP Distributions - Amazon CloudFront](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-rtmp.html)

Comment: I want my video to be downloaded first and then be played. How do I reference my AWS account ID with my video link? When I run the url, I get a access denied. When I make it public, then I can access the url. How can I use the url without making it public?

Comment: See: [Share an Object with Others - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html)

Comment: I don't want to share my object with others. I want to use my object with my account id.

Comment: Please read the documentation. The method is that the object remains private. Your application can generate a time-limited URL ("Pre-Signed URL") that it can provide to users. They can then use the URL within a given time period to access the object. After that time period, the link no longer works. This way, the object is not publicly available.

Comment: WOW. So I'm left with no choice but to make it public. Is there any other Cloud Service which can be restricted and accessed easily?

Comment: I think we are both confused by what the other person is saying. If you have a set of AWS Credentials (eg an Access Key and Secret Key), and the IAM User associated with those credentials has access to the bucket or object, then they will be able to access the object. However, an Access Key and Secret Key is normally used to call the AWS API, not to access objects via an HTTP URL. It _is_ possible to use Access Key and Secret Key to access via a URL, but you need to calculate a _Signature_ using the Secret Key that grants permission, so they Secret Key is not exposed.